# Foliation of the phase space

Tags: classical-mechanics, differential-geometry, hamiltonian-formalism

Consider an arbitrary classical Hamiltonian system. Given an initial state $(p_0, q_0)$, we can get a solution of the equation of motion, a curve in the phase space. Now the problem is, for a generic system, cannot such curves foliate the phase space? If not, what is the mechanism?

Comment: Are you aware of [Frobenious theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_%28differential_topology%29)? Also, what *type* of foliation are you looking for? The foliation appearing in the integrability statements? The Lagrangian folitations needed for variants of maximal integrability or prequantization? Please give more details on what you are looking for.

Comment: I know the Frobenious theorem. Yes, we have a vector field on the phase space, and by the Frobenious theorem, this vector field is integrable and there should be a foliation.